# Shape clipped by invisible object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

I'm drawing in Inkscape a map for a design project I'm working on.
At the bottom of the map I have a legend with all the symbols I use.

I noticed that one of the symbol(the blue arrow) seems to be clipped at the bottom by something invisible.

[image]

If I move this arrow up it appears unclipped

[image]

If I move it down or try to extend it down, the clipping appears even more.

[image]

[image]

- I tried to close/reopen Inkscape, no luck
- I tried to alt+click to select an invisible object, nothing
- I tried to hide all other layers but the one the arrow is on, didn't change anything
- I tried to duplicate the arrow, same problem
- I tried drawing new shape, same stuff

When I move another shape in this area, suddenly the arrow is revealed. ??

[image]

Would you guys have any idea if this could be fixed and how?

TIA

Comment: When you select that object 'Robinet' what the status bar at the bottom tells you? or could you share the a minimal svg file that has that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to solve this (except by guessing) without knowing how the SVG is constructed. It can have an unknown amount of multi-level groups and clipping paths.

People often get into troubles like this when they import something, for ex. a PDF which contains vectors.

Try Extension > Arrange > Deep Ungroup and Object > Clip > Release. Delete the redundant shapes which become accessible with these.

No guarantee. That was only a guess.

Help yourself and learn from the User's Guide to see what Objects panel tells of the structure and how to use it to select the redundant parts.

NOTE: You'll have a theoretical possibility to get a pinpoint answer instead of guesses if you insert a download link to a SVG file where the problem occurs as a commentator has already suggested. Be sure that the link needs no login.